# If user authenticate for parent website then no need to enter credentials for child website

Tags: asp.net, .net, web-services, c#-4.0, authentication

I am working with asp.net.I have two website(**Parent.com and child.com**) in different servers and both websites having its own login screen **I want to provide automatic authenticate for child.com when a user logged in from Parent.com website** if the user will trying to open child.com and he is already logged in to the parent.com website then no need to show the login screen of child.com it will automatic authenticate that user and he will able enter the child.com website freely.Please suggest me how would I do that.
Thanks
Prafulla

Answer (score 0):

You can Configure a SQL Server to Maintain Session State, [see here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753897%28v=ws.10%29.aspx), and set both these websites to have the same Session state management.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the same machineKey in both web.configs.

In that case you'll get what you need.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eb0zx8fc.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I would to like implement similar functionality but for cross domain and cross platform web site.
I have a requirement as below.
I have a parent website which has its own login implementation .I have a link to a child website on a page.The child website can be accessed only form the parent site.If user accesses the child URL directly he should get a page not found page.There is not login page in child website.
Also both parent and child sites can send-receive data between them.The child website can be accessed by multiple parent site.
Can you please let me know how we can achieve session functionality in above scenario.
How we can use web services in above scenario?
What parameters I need to consider for managing the communication between these multiple site.

Please let me know if I need to provide some more information